# Selecting the text before a search query in perl

Tags: perl

I am searching a variable for a search term, and would like to be to find the search term  in perl within the variable, and when it is found select the data before it. i.e search through this data below for: "Looking for Beta testers for new dating game" and be able to select the date and put it in a variable

Sep 19 Hyper.IS IOS 8 Updated Interest Based Social Network (Beta Testers)     (NYC)   pic map       Sep 19 Looking for Beta testers for new dating game.     (online)   pic map

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more lines to describe it properly and if possible share the code which you are trying and is not working. We will be glad to help you after that :)

Comment: See [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

I did it by using the following regex expression:

```
my ($year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec) = $get_time =~ /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d?\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/;
```